# Combining NLog with SQLite and WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, nlog

I'm using NLog and SQLite in my C# WPF application, and the NLog config is set up with the SQLite database as a target.  And logging to the SQLite database works fine.

Now I want to present (some of) the log messages in a `ListView` (or similar), i.e. place log messages in a `ObservableCollection` that the control can bind to.  I want to show the messages as they are logged, but also have possibility to filter messages on timestamp, log level, key words in log message, etc.  What would be a good approach for doing this?

I thought about writing a custom NLog target that puts entries in a `ObservableCollection`.  But that will perhaps make it difficult to add filter functionality.  Another possibility is perhaps to monitor changes in the SQLite database in some way, read back the changes and update the `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: There is a target "[Memory](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Memory-target)" which could be of use here.

Comment: Another candidate might be a Message Queue target: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/MSMQ-target

Comment: For windows forms, there are also targets for control and richtextbox, but they obviously do not apply here (since you are on wpf).

Comment: Try to set up a chainsaw target and implement tcp listener.

Comment: Please comment if downvoting, so I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the log to be kept between program runs then I would say to continue saving them to SQLite as you are doing at the moment and write a form that queries that database with what ever criteria you want. I have done a similar thing using NHibernate to handle the database IO.

If however the log is just needed during the runtime of the program then either do the same as above but use an in memory SQLite database or use the memory target of NLog and query that array list using LINQ

Comment: Nah, between program runs won't be necessary, as I can just read e.g. the 200 latest log entries or something at application startup.  The Memory NLog target looks interesting.  Is an in-memory SQLite database an additional database to the file database (i.e. two database targets in NLog configuration), or somehow a mirror section of the file database?

Comment: You could then write out to both an in memory SQLite database (for quicker querying) and then also to the database on disk to keep it for later. In memory SQLite databases are very handy for this type of thing and if you use NHibernate then if you did ever want to switch and read for the "real" database use just change connection

Comment: I'm using Dapper, but swapping connections should be just as easy there, I gather.  Thank you for the ideas.  I'll set the question as answered.